# Speed of cell signal to protein production

Tags: transcription, translation, protein-expression

How long does a cell take to make a protein from the point of receiving the signal to produce the protein? Does the cell have stores of the protein ready to release or is the protein created in real-time (transcription -> translation -> protein release)? Does this vary depending on the type of protein?

I have read articles that describe transcription as fast as 40 - 80 nucleotides per second. The same articles described translation as taking a similar amount of time. Taking into account the time it takes to move the mRNA from the nucleus to the ER and then to the point where the resultant protein is ready to secrete, how long does it take?

Comment: Totally depends on the pathway and protein and what you measure.

Comment: @BryanKrause What are some general estimates? Perhaps an example of a specific protein?

Comment: Milliseconds to days.